# Arduino with C: standard/pins_arduino.h error

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno

I am attempting to write a test program for an arduino uno, using the `pins_arduino.h` file found in `hardware/variants/standard` (I chose this one because there was no `arduino_uno` folder or similar in the hardware/variants folder, and the uno is kind of the standard arduino). Following [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-Arduino-Software-in-C) guide (may be outdated - if there is a better one please link me) to be able to write in plain C. when I try to compile, I get an error in `pins_arduino.h` with a series of symbols unable to be resolved. These symbols are found in this snippet:

```
const uint8_t PROGMEM digital_pin_to_port_PGM[] = {
PD, /* 0 */
PD,
PD,
PD,
PD,
PD,
PD,
PD,
PB, /* 8 */
PB,
PB,
PB,
PB,
PB,
PC, /* 14 */
PC,
PC,
PC,
PC,
PC,
```

};

The error is: `Description  Resource    Path    Location    Type
Symbol 'PD' could not be resolved   pins_arduino.h  /Ardurino 1 line 133    Semantic Error` (and more, one for each "PC", "PB" and "PD" in the array)

I assume these are probably just numbers, based on this snippet from earlier in `pins_arduino.h`:

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 14;
static const uint8_t A1 = 15;
static const uint8_t A2 = 16;
static const uint8_t A3 = 17;
static const uint8_t A4 = 18;
static const uint8_t A5 = 19;
static const uint8_t A6 = 20;
static const uint8_t A7 = 21;
```

Is there a file I am missing that supplies these varaibles?
Can I just define these as some numbers (and what numbers)?

do I just have to suck it up and learn the arduino language and use their supplied IDE (I really don't need another single-purpose IDE on my computer)?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those symbols are defined in the Arduino.h (`hardware/cores/arduino`) file:

```
#ifdef ARDUINO_MAIN
  #define PA 1
  #define PB 2
  #define PC 3
  #define PD 4
  #define PE 5
  #define PF 6
  #define PG 7
  #define PH 8
  #define PJ 10
  #define PK 11
  #define PL 12
#endif
```

There are also other things defined in Arduino.h that are used in pins_arduino.h so you may want to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed the issue by adding `#include "digital_wiring.c"` to the top of `Arduino.h`.